# Reading auto increment column during INSERT INTO query

Tags: php, mysql

I was wondering if it is possible to read the value of a column that is set to auto increment for a row that is going to be inserted? I plan on encoding the `order_id` column for the row (auto increment primary key) to a `transaction_id` will be a publicly viewable ID.

So instead of the client searching `http://website.com/order.php?order_id=3` it will read something like `http://website.com/order.php?transaction_id=188117104`.

Here is how I will be hashing the `order_id` to a publicly viewable `transaction_id`.

```
base_convert(  hash( "adler32", $string ), 36, 10 )
```

Is there a way I can get the `order_id` column so I can modify it to the `transaction_id` column before the query is executed to insert the record into the database?

Thanks.

EDIT 1:

Using mysql_last_id is it possible to do this in a single query?

```
<?php

// Insert records for product_orders
mysql_query('
    INSERT INTO ' . DB_PFIX . 'product_orders (
        order_transaction_id
    ) VALUES (
        "' . base_convert(  hash( "adler32", "LAST_INSERT_ID" + 1 ), 36, 10 ) . '"
    ), (
        "' . base_convert(  hash( "adler32", "LAST_INSERT_ID" + 1 ), 36, 10 ) . '"
    ), (
        "' . base_convert(  hash( "adler32", "LAST_INSERT_ID" + 1 ), 36, 10 ) . '"
    ), (
        "' . base_convert(  hash( "adler32", "LAST_INSERT_ID" + 1 ), 36, 10 ) . '"
    ), (
        "' . base_convert(  hash( "adler32", "LAST_INSERT_ID" + 1 ), 36, 10 ) . '"
    )
') or die (
    mysql_error()
);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't support sequences so getting a NEXTVAL isn't easy. It's a pretty bad idea to attempt this as having more than one user creating inserts could lead to wrong IDs being returned. A better idea would be to do a two phased commit (or even return the last_insert_id to PHP and then perform another query) I'd go for a two phased transaction using the mysql_insert_id. Then do your logic and update the row.

Comment: Is it possible to do something like in EDIT 1 above?